# A question about series with a strange property.

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, analysis, contest-math

Does there exist a sequence $\left(a_n\right)_{n\ge1}$ with $a_n < a_{n+1}+a_{n^2}, \forall n=1,2,3,\ldots$ such that the series $\displaystyle{\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}a_n}$ converges?

This is the **first** part of [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242190/does-there-exist-a-sequence-a-n-n-ge1-with-a-n-a-n1a-n2-such) question which has an (accepted) answer for its **second** part only:
The last sentence of the [answer](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/245596/39722) is: 
 "Now we note that $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i\geq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i\in J_k}a_i>\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}a_n$, so the sum diverges."
For the inequality $\sum_{i=1}^{\infty}a_i\geq\sum_{k=0}^{\infty}\sum_{i\in J_k}a_i$ to be valid, we have to assume the positivity of $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ since $\displaystyle{\bigcup_{k\in\mathbb N}J_k\neq\mathbb N}$.

According to the [comments](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242190/does-there-exist-a-sequence-a-n-n-ge1-with-a-n-a-n1a-n2-such?lq=1#comment556592_242190) the first part is a difficult question.

Comment: @AymanHourieh: The answer to the second part is that there is **not** such a (positive) sequence.

Comment: @mjqxxxx: For $n=1$ the inequality $a_n<a_{n+1}+a_{n^2}$ becomes $a_2>0$ so the sequence cannot be always negative.

Comment: This is one of those graveyard questions -- four deleted answers within one hour.

Comment: @user7530: The sequence $(a_n)_{n\in\mathbb N}$ must contain a strictly positive subsequence. Can you explain more how non-existence follows from the linked proof? I believe it doesn't.

Comment: @RossMillikan: [This](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/242190/does-there-exist-a-sequence-a-n-n-ge1-with-a-n-a-n1a-n2-such) question has an accepted answer only for its second part. Not for the one I am asking. If this is against the rules of the site I will delete it.

Comment: @Pambos You're right, it does not.

Comment: @user7530: since this question was closed by the community, the standard thing to do to request for re-open votes is to [open a re-open request like this](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/a/7068/1543) on meta.

Comment: @George you can only ping one user per comment. So only Ross would be notified by your comment above.

Comment: @Willie Thanks for the info.

Comment: Someone pointed out in a comment to my flawed (and now deleted) answer that the positivity of the terms is used in the penultimate inequality of the accepted answer to the linked question. I think you should explain this in the question, since it's not *entirely* obvious why that answer answers only the first part of the question.

Comment: The linked question has two parts: 1) Does such a sequence exist?  and 2) Does such a positive termed sequence exist?

The linked question has an answer for part 2, but not part 1.

Comment: Anyone else find it interesting the original question was tagged (contest-math)?  If this was for a contest, shouldn't there be a solution posted somewhere?

Comment: @anorton: I'm not sure whom or what your first comment was directed at. In case it was in response to mine: Yes, the present question already clearly states that; what it doesn't state is *why* the answer to the other question only answers the second part. The answer itself doesn't say that; it purports to answer the entire question and never explicitly assumes positivity of the terms; I was just saying that it would be good to state in the present question where that answer does implicitly assume positivity, since it's not entirely obvious (at least it wasn't to me).

Comment: @joriki: You are right, I should have added that part. I believe now is OK. BTW (as far as I can remember) I never saw your answer.

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Yes, if negative elements are allowed, the series can be made to converge.  The basic idea is to first fix the values at the square positions, and then use the remaining freedom to create subsequences between those positions that sum to $0$ and whose partial sums are bounded by a decreasing function.  Specifically, for each $k \ge 1$ and $0 \le l \le 2k$, let $a_{k^2 + l}=b_{k}(1- c_{k,l})$, where $(b_k)_{k\ge 1}$ is a positive sequence that converges monotonically to zero, $c_{k,0}=0$ (so $a_{k^2}=b_{k}$), and $c_{k,l}$ is non-decreasing for each $k$.  Then for each $k \ge 1$ and $0 \le l < 2k$ we have the "internal constraints,"
$$
b_{k}(1-c_{k,l})=a_{k^2+l}<a_{k^2+l+1}+a_{(k^2+l)^2}=a_{k^2+l+1}+b_{k^2+l}=b_{k}(1-c_{k,l+1})+b_{k^2+l},
$$
and for each $k \ge 1$ we have the "join constraint,"
$$
b_{k}(1-c_{k,2k}) = a_{k^2+2k}<a_{k^2+2k+1}+a_{(k^2+2k)^2}=b_{k+1}+b_{k^2+2k}.
$$
We will guarantee the internal constraints are met by imposing a stricter constraint for each $k$:
$$
\max_{0\le l < 2k}(c_{k,l+1}-c_{k,l})\le \frac{b_{(k+1)^2}}{b_{k}};
$$
using this, we see that
$$
c_{k,l+1}-c_{k,l}\le \max_{0\le l < 2k}(c_{k,l+1}-c_{k,l})\le \frac{b_{(k+1)^2}}{b_{k}} < \frac{b_{k^2+l}}{b_{k}}
$$
does hold for each $k$ and $l$.  The join constraint is met if $$c_{k,2k} > 1-\frac{b_{k+1}+b_{k^2+2k}}{b_k};$$
in particular, since $(b_{k})$ is positive, it's sufficient to have $c_{k,2k}\ge 1$.
Now, for $k>1$ we can take $c_{k,l}=1$ except for $c_{k,0}=0$, $c_{k,1}=1/2$, $c_{k,2k-1}=3/2$, and $c_{k,2k}=2$.  For $k=1$ we will take $c_{k,0}=0$, $c_{k,1}=1/2$, and $c_{k,2}=1$.  Then the join constraint is met, and the internal constraint becomes
$$
\frac{b_{(k+1)^2}}{b_{k}} \ge \max_{0\le l < 2k}(c_{k,l+1}-c_{k,l})=\frac{1}{2},
$$
which limits how quickly $(b_{k})$ can converge to $0$.  For example, we can choose
$$
b_{k}=\frac{1}{\sqrt{\log(k+1)}}.
$$
The resulting sequence does what we want.  For each $k>1$, the subsequence from position $k^2$ to position $(k+1)^2-1$, inclusive, sums to zero, and its partial sums are never larger than $\frac{3}{2}b_{k}$, a bound that decreases (albeit slowly) to zero as $k\rightarrow\infty$.  The overall series, therefore, converges to the sum of the first three terms, which is $\frac{3}{2}b_1$.  The sequence consists of a series of EEG-like "blips" of four non-zero values at the square positions; each blip has a slightly smaller amplitude than the last.

Comment: +1, very nice. Just an irrelevant detail: The value of $a_1$ is actually arbitrary, so $c_{k,0}=1$ is OK, but from your  announcement that $c_{k,l}$ is non-decreasing for each $k$ and from the sum $\frac32b_1$ for the first three terms it seems that you intended $c_{k,0}=0$?

Comment: This answer is a model of clarity and concision.

Comment: @joriki: Thanks, that was indeed a typo.

Comment: Nice answer! Thanks.